# ASCii value of ü in C++

Tags: c++, windows, encoding, ascii

According to [that](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/capital-letter-a-uppercase-ascii-code-65.html) site ASCii value of ü is 129 but when I run printf("%d",'ü') code, output is -4. What's the cause of that?

Comment: It's not ASCII. It's extended ASCII.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of character encoding.

Comment: There's absolutely no guarantee that the execution character set for your compiler is ASCII at all and especially not that it's that specific extended ASCII set.

Comment: ASCII is language dependent

Comment: It's not ASCII. ASCII characters do not include any accented/etc characters.

Comment: @fatih_k: Actually, it's not. ASCII is a very well-defined 7-bit encoding. Its successor standard ISO 646 allowed for extensions, which are language-dependent, which led in turn to ISO-8859. As that proved to be inadequate as well, we now have Unicode and UTF-8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you get a -4 is basically pure chance, as it is depending on the locale setting of your environment and the implementation of your compiler.

Others already pointed out that, depending on whether your platform considers `char` to be signed or not, printing a char value as if it were an integer might yield negative numbers for values of `0x80` and higher.

---

As for encodings (and be aware that below list is by no means exhaustive):

`ü` does not have an ASCII value, as (US-) [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only defines characters up to 0x7f (127).

[IBM Codepage 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) and [850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) (DOS) have `ü` at `0x81`, which is -127 or 129 depending on signedness.

[ISO-8859-1 through -4, -9, -10, and -13 through -16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) as well as Windows codepages [1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) and [1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) have `ü` at `0xfc` (-4 / 252). The other ISO-8859 encodings don't have the `ü` in their character set.

[UTF-8](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) - which everyone should be using instead of those 8-bit encodings of yesteryear for a [variety](http://utf8everywhere.org/) of [reasons](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) - encodes `ü` as the two-byte sequence `0xc3 0xbc`.

I've put together a side-by-side codepage for personal use, if you are interested you can find it at [my homepage](http://www.rootdirectory.de/chrome/site/encoding.html).

---

Once you have stomached that, be aware that the standard defines two [character sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#Character_set), one for the representation of source, and one for the representation of strings in the executable code. Neither contains any characters beyond the basic A-Z range, the two might actually be different (think cross-compiler), and neither has its numerical representation defined - i.e. you might actually be looking at [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), where characters aren't even encoded with *consecutive* values (i.e., `assert( 'Z' - 'A' == 26 )` would fail).

You think that's funny? Well, basically your machine doesn't even have to provide characters like `@`, as that is ASCII, but *not* part of the basic character set. ;-)

Generally speaking, once you use non-ASCII characters in source, you left well-defined behaviour behind and are relying on the implementation / environment.

Comment: About using non-ASCII in source: I think it's slowly becoming normal or at least acceptable to use UTF-8 for source files. It should also be perfectly well defined behaviour on any relatively recent compiler/language.

Comment: @hyde: Personally, I feel that every software should properly support UTF-8, *but that source code should be strictly ASCII-7*. Identifiers and comments should be plain English anyway for simplicity (this coming from a German). Program strings should be located in an *external* text file (encoded UTF-8), and handled by the localization framework. And ASCII-7 is the only encoding you can reliably, automatically *test* for. Which is something your environment should be set up to do before every commit. (While you're at it, check for space vs. tab indenting as well.)

Comment: This is coming from first-hand pains experienced. We literally lost **days** hunting and fixing a bug resulting from the ambiguity of `š` (0x9a in Windows, 0xa8 in ISO-8859-15, 0xc5 0xa1 in UTF-8). Too many people, including otherwise skilled developers, don't know, don't care, or forget about character encodings from time to time. Text be UTF-8, source be ASCII-7. IMHO.

Comment: I agree that using UTF-8 needs more care, but I've done my share of writing \xxx codes to string literals when using ASCII-only source, as well as writing less-than-ideal comments due to lack of native chars, so based on this I'd say, *iff* it benefits the project, deciding to use UTF-8 is sensible. It requires briefing every developer about the implications, but poor project management or developer discipline is a bad excuse.

Comment: @hyde: Agreed - *if* it benefits the project, UTF-8 is the only sensible choice. (Even among the Unicode encodings, since it's the most portable, and the only one you cannot get wrong re endianess, which is the *other* subject a surprising many developers turn out to be ignorant of.)

Answer (score 2):

On your system char is a signed type. You should first convert to an unsigned type before printing.

```
printf("%d", (unsigned char)'ü');
```

Whether this will print the 129 you expect is another matter, but it will at least print the encoding of ü in your *execution character set*.

Answer (score 1):

%d is printing a signed decimal number, which for a byte would print in the range of -128-127).  You probably want to use unsigned (%u) which will output the expected 0-255.

Comment: Probably you actually want `printf("%d", (unsigned char)'ü')`. A negative integer is not going to convert to a unsigned value in a straightforward way.

Comment: Char can be either signed or unsigned (allowed by the C and C++ standards). If it's 8-bit, it can be either -128 to +127 or 0 to 255.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: ...or -127 to +127 (ones complement or sign/magnitude).

Comment: Agree.  Since the output is a negative value, I was presuming that the target platform's character was signed.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Or it could even be not 8 bit at all. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: Yes, but he did start with: "If it's 8-bit..."